# WPF ScrollViewer align to content

Tags: wpf

I have a scrollviewer with some panels, and have enabled touch - sliding by setting the panning mode, all works fine. But how would I make the scrollviewer jump / align / synchronise to the content as I swipe, like my android phone does when I swipe sideways, for example?

Comment: Ca you show us some code, and explain on it what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have no code! I can slide my borders in a scrollviewer with a touchscreen, works fine. But when the sliding stops, it is randomly anywhere - might be with one half of one border and another half of another - I just want it to do like the desktop on an android phone, and to center the nearest border in the visible area.